# How to resume wget mirroring from a different location?

Tags: linux, windows-xp, download, cygwin, wget

I am out of space in my home folder , where iam currently mirroring  this [site](http://mirror.pkill.info/cygwin/x86) for the pupose of a cygwin installation in my windows machine using wget from my linux machine.

i am aware that i can continue with interrupted downloads by using "-c" option in wget but ,since there is no space left on the drive and the mirroring doesn't seem to stop i intend to move the partial mirrored content to another drive and resume mirroring.Will this cause the wget to start all over again and render the currently downloaded contents useless ? Is there anything i can do about it or should i start it all over again from a drive with lots of empty space ? I have alredy downloaded more than 1 gb,i am low on my band width and i dont want to take chances.

(ps:currently mirroring is suspended.)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and it works :

1. Copy the wget log files and paste them in the directory you wish to resume mirroring.(*I don't know if it matters at all*)
2. **cd** to the directory where you wish to resume mirroring.
3. Resume the mirroring with **-c** option.